# How many even/odd numbers can be formed within a specified range?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Consider
>
> $$A = \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6\}$$
>
> a) How many $3$ digit even numbers between $200$ and $500$ can be formed?
>
> b) How many $3$ digit odd numbers between $240$ and $600$ can be formed?

For the part a, we have that

$$P = (5)(6)(3) = 90$$

For the part b, we have that

$$P = (5)(2)(3) = 30$$

Am I wrong?

**EDIT:** Repetation is ALLOWED.

Regards.

Comment: When you pose an attempt, you should explain your reasoning so that users can identify any errors you may have made.

Comment: The answer depends on whether repetition of digits is permitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $(a)$, they have first digit $2,3$ or $4$, and last digit $2,4$ or $6$.  So, $3\cdot 6\cdot 3=54$.

For $(b)$, first digit can be $2,3,4$ or $5$.  Second digit can be $4,5$ or $6$ when the first digit is $2$, and the last digit is $1,3$ or $5$.  So $3\cdot3=9$ for when the first digit is two.  Then when the first digit is $3,4$ or $5$, we have any of the six for the second,  and $1,3$ or $5$ for the third.   So, $3\cdot 6\cdot 3=54$.  So we get $54+9=63$.

Comment: Ok.  The second part is a little harder.  I also corrected a mistake in the first part...